# Easiest way to copy data from one table to another table?

Tags: sql

After grabbing result, what is the easiest way to grab certain fields from #result and put them into a different table (the data types might not match, which will require some conversions).

```
select * into #result from table1
```

Can I do a "SELECT * INTO" or maybe a cursor to loop through #result and insert it into the destination table?  Is there an even better way?

Comment: Sql database using sql server management studio, does that define the type?

Comment: "sql database" is not a product. But I guess you mean Microsoft SQL Server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way (if supported by the database in question) is to use an `INSERT` statement with a SELECT clause.  For example:

```
INSERT INTO targettable (val1, val2) 
       SELECT someval1, someval2 FROM sourcetable
```

Comment: I'm not aware of any sql database that does *not* support it

Comment: +1 to this answer. I asked for the database because I knew SELECT INTO didn't work in some (MySQL, others?)